# Compute the mean of every X rows of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I coded a little loop that reduces a dataset by computing the mean of X rows every X rows. 
I'm working with a dataset of a certain size (8 Millions rows for 10 columns) and my code takes too long to compute the whole dataset.
I am using Pandas.
Is there a way to improve my loop to make it more efficient and faster ?

```py
# data is the dataset, pd.DataFrame()
#
# nb_row is the number of rows to collapse
#   for example : nb_row = 12 would reduce the dataset by x12
#   by computing the mean of 12 rows every 12 rows

nb_row = 12
raw_columns = ["f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"] # column names
for i in range(0, len(data), nb_row):
    new_df = new_df.append(
        pd.DataFrame(
            [[data[elem].iloc[i : i + nb_row].mean() for elem in raw_columns]],
            columns=raw_columns,
        )
    )
```

Thanks

Comment: Is one of those "x rows" in the top row supposed to be something else? Otherwise, I think youve pretty much got it covered... : )   3 out of 3 ain't bad; it's perfect! ...sry, I would've edited, but it's slightly over my head. Didn't want to mess it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code breaks two major pandas antipatterns, explained in depth by [@cs95](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/cs95):

- [Avoid iterating a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/13138364)
- [Avoid growing a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56746204/13138364)

The more idiomatic approaches are [`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) (fastest) and [`rolling.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.mean.html):

[image]

---

#### 1. [`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) (fastest)

(This is ~5.5x faster than [`rolling.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.mean.html) at 8M rows.)

Generate pseudo-groups with `data.index // nb_row` and take the [`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
nb_row = 12
new_df = data.groupby(data.index // nb_row).mean()

#               f1        f2        f3        f4
# 0      -0.171037 -0.288915  0.026885 -0.083732
# 1      -0.018497  0.329961  0.107714 -0.430527
# ...          ...       ...       ...       ...
# 666665 -0.648026  0.232827  0.290072  0.535636
# 666666 -0.373699 -0.260689  0.122012 -0.217035
# 
# [666667 rows x 4 columns]
```

Note that if the real `data` has a custom index (instead of a default `RangeIndex`), then use `groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // nb_row)` instead.

---

#### 2. [`rolling.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.mean.html)

[rak1507's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/269965/238890) covers [`rolling.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.mean.html) but is missing a key detail.

`rolling(nb_row)` uses a window size of `nb_row` **but slides 1 row at a time, not every `nb_row` rows.**

- That means slicing with `[nb_row-1:]` results in the wrong output shape (it's not reduced by a factor of `nb_row` as described in the OP):

  ```
  new_df = data.rolling(nb_row).mean()[nb_row-1:]
  new_df.shape

  # (7999989, 4)
  ```
- Instead we should slice with `[nb_row::nb_row]` to get every `nb_row`<sup>th</sup> row:

  ```
  new_df = data.rolling(nb_row).mean()[nb_row::nb_row]
  new_df.shape

  # (666666, 4)
  ```

---

#### Timings (8M rows*)

```
%timeit data.groupby(data.index // nb_row).mean()
631 ms ± 56.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
%timeit data.rolling(nb_row).mean()[nb_row::nb_row]
3.47 s ± 274 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

<sup>** `data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((8_000_000, 4)), columns=['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4'])`*</sup>

Comment: Oops yeah you're right I forgot to slice every nth element too. Nice answer - til about groupby